# Getting access to Object#try

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to obtain access to Object#try in ruby.

I thought that just including activesupport would do the trick, but it doesn't.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'active_support'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> o = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x15d45d9>
irb(main):004:0> o.respond_to? :try
=> false
irb(main):005:0>
```

How do I get access to `Object#try`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get try all you need to do is `require "active_support/core_ext/object/try"`. The [source is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb) and because the `NilClass` is opened and `try` is defined to return nil, you get the chaining ability.

Comment: @Christopher Maujean Your point? `try` isn't supposed to gobble up `NoMethodError`s, it's meant to stop you from calling any method on a `NilClass`.